# How can I prevent onTapCancel from being triggered by the child element?

Tags: flutter

In flutter, I have a GestureDetector-wrapped Container with a Text child.

- GestureDetector

  - AnimatedContainer

    - Container

      - Text("Start")

When the button is tapped, the shadow will compress, creating a push-down animation effect.

[image]

My Code:

```dart
class _ActionButtonState extends State<ActionButton> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      // behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,

      onTapDown: (e) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
        });
      },
      onTapCancel: () => setState(() {
        isPressed = false;
      }),

      onTapUp: (e) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
        });
      },

      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: isPressed ? 0 : 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColor.btnShadowColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.radius),
        ),

        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 8),
        
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColor.btnColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.radius),
          ),
        
          child: Text("Start", style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.whiteText,
          ),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue arises when the pointer moves to the Text widget, causing GestureDetector to trigger onTapCancel. As a result, the button reverts to its original state.

In my opinon, mouse is not released, and is not leaving the Container. So onTapCancel should not be triggered.

I tried many ways of searching the answer, but I got nothing.
I expect someone can help on prevent onTapCancel from being triggered by the child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the Flutter's github issues, i found this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19783#issuecomment-654052524

Replace the GestureDetector with Listener widget

```
class ActionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ActionButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<ActionButton> createState() => _ActionButtonState();
}

class _ActionButtonState extends State<ActionButton> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (e) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
        });
      },
      onPointerCancel: (_) => setState(() {
        isPressed = false;
        log("tapCancel");
      }),

      onPointerUp: (e) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
          log("tapUp");
        });
      },

      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: isPressed ? 0 : 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: const Text(
            "Start",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: a gif of working example]

### Edit

Apparently, `onPointerUp` is still called even when pointer is outside the widget. This is hacky, but i think adding a position check does the job;

```dart
  bool isOutside(BuildContext context, Offset postion) {
    return postion.dx < 0 ||
        postion.dy < 0 ||
        postion.dx > (context.size?.width ?? 0) ||
        postion.dy > (context.size?.height ?? 0);
  }
```

```dart
onPointerUp: (e) {
  setState(() {
    isPressed = false;
  });

  if (isOutside(context, e.localPosition)) {
    return;
  }

  // Do something when pointer is inside Listener here
  log("hello");
},
```

Comment: Good answer :) except the button is triggered even when the user moves the mouse/finger outside the button, so its kinda forced and cannot be canceled. A solution to that is to wrap the `Listener` widget inside a `GestureDetector` widget and use the `onTap` property for any functions other than `isPressed=false;`

Comment: @Texv Thanks i didn't know. There is this flutter issue  "onPointerCancel of Listener in never called" https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93683. The only solution i could think of is adding a check if pointer is inside widget.

Comment: It's not an issue, it just has a different behaviour than expected. It's meant to work for when the click is interrupted by something else such as popups, loading, disconnect, etc. Having the Listener as a child of the GestureDetector works best.